# How can I hide white box icon from day pilot scheduler from tree resource?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am using day pilot scheduler in my project. I want to hide the white box from child node of day pilot scheduler, as shown in the picture:

[image]

Comment: From the info provided there is no clue of what control is the one used in the screenshot. Consider adding a more detailed question and providing a [mcve]

Comment: protected override void OnLoadNode(LoadNodeArgs e)
            {
                Resource child = new Resource();
                foreach (DataRow coaches in new EventManager().GetCoachForResources(Convert.ToInt32(e.Resource.Id)).Rows)
                {
                    e.Resource.Children.Add((string)coaches["Name"], Convert.ToString(coaches["Id"]));
                    e.Resource.Expanded = true;
                  
                }
                Update(CallBackUpdateType.Full);
            }

Answer (score 0):

You can hide columns using OnIncludeCell event handler:

```
    protected override void OnIncludeCell(IncludeCellArgs e)
    {
       // hiding lunch break
       if (e.Start.Hour == 13)
          e.Visible = false;
    }
```

Documentation link: https://doc.daypilot.org/scheduler/hiding-time-columns/

Comment: It's better to give a demonstration here instead of pasting a link

Comment: Hi, i added a onloadNode(LoadNodeArgs) evnt how to set visible false in this.

Answer (score 0):

I used DOM inspection to find if those elements had any particularity that I could use to interact with.
It looks like the attributed class is unique so I used it with jQuery to simply remove it from the DOM.

My code was simply this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.scheduler_8_tree_image_no_children').each(function () {
            $(this).remove(); //removing square image for tree elements that have no children
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove class **scheduler_default_tree_image_no_children** from daypilot-min.js

```
e.add(".scheduler_default_tree_image_no_children", "background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAJCAIAAABv85FHAAAAKXRFWHRDcmVhdGlvbiBUaW1lAHDhIDMwIEkgMjAwOSAwODo0NjozMSArMDEwMClDkt4AAAAHdElNRQfZAR4HLzEyzsCJAAAACXBIWXMAAA7CAAAOwgEVKEqAAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAADBJREFUeNpjrK6s5uTl/P75OybJ0NLW8h8bAIozgeSxAaA4E1A7VjmgOL31MeLxHwCeXUT0WkFMKAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);")
```

this white space is an image. You have to remove it from js.